# ASPNET CORE APP ON IIS SUB APP NOT TO SHARE COOKIES

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, cookies

I'm really new on web dev, i have a little aspnet core 3.1 app developed that use own authentication, i mean cookie-base auth through HttpContext.SignInAsync against a dbase user table.
The thing is that i have 2 clients and I want to host in IIS as two sub folders, i mean: MAIN_APP\SUB_APP_1 and MAIN_APP\SUB_APP_2, both are the same app, converted to application but pointing to different db acord to client... so i would need to treat each cookie (auth and others used) separated however both are recording under MAIN_APP, so if the CEO (which can access both sub apps) wants to login in both at the same time is imposible, because one cookie revoke the other one...
It is possible to store (local storage, cookies, etc) in the sub app for the browser? Can you please help me with this issue?
Pd, sorry if i'm being extremely beginner... or if i'm asking something stupid.
Regards!
Martin

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the client sill store the cookie based on the domain name. If you want to achieve SSO, you should make sure the two application has the same domain name like:

`aa.domain.com` and `bb.domain.com`.

Besides, if you couldn't have the same domain, that means we couldn't share the token from two web application.